# SQL Server trigger: identify specific Update statement use

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, database-trigger

I need to use a series of relatively simple update statements on a large table, for example as below:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = 'A' 
WHERE Col2 = '1'

UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = 'A' 
WHERE Col3 = 'X'

UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = 'B' 
WHERE Col2 = '2'
```

I am using a trigger to track which records are updated. How would I go about identifying which specific update statement had resulted in the update in the table output from the trigger?

Would it be possible to reference a variable set next to the update statement in the trigger script?

Comment: `DROP TRIGGER`, `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Search for `DBCC INPUTBUFFER`.

Comment: `WHERE`, not `WHEN` ...

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you may want to find out what exact statement that updated your table. Or you may want to find out how the `WHERE` clause of the `DELETE` statement (Executed by someone) looked like.

`DBCC INPUTBUFFER` can provide you with this kind of information. You can create a trigger on your table, that uses `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` command to find out the exact command that caused the trigger to fire.

The following trigger code works in SQL Sever 2000 (In SQL Server 7.0, you can't create tables inside a trigger. So, you'll have to create a permanent table before hand and use that inside the trigger). This code only displays the SQL statement, login name, user name and current time, but you can alter the code, so that this information gets logged in a table for tracking/auditing purposes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName 
ON TableName 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON

 DECLARE @ExecStr varchar(50), @Qry nvarchar(255)

 CREATE TABLE #inputbuffer 
 (
  EventType nvarchar(30), 
  Parameters int, 
  EventInfo nvarchar(255)
 )

 SET @ExecStr = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + STR(@@SPID) + ')'

 INSERT INTO #inputbuffer 
 EXEC (@ExecStr)

 SET @Qry = (SELECT EventInfo FROM #inputbuffer)

 SELECT @Qry AS 'Query that fired the trigger', 
 SYSTEM_USER as LoginName, 
 USER AS UserName, 
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS CurrentTime
END
```

From the above code, replace the `TableName` and `TriggerName` with your table name and trigger name respectively and you can test the trigger by creating the trigger first and then by inserting/updating/deleting data.

Taken from [here!](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/tracking_sql_statements_by_triggers.htm)

Comment: Can you please explain the solution you've linked. The resource may go offline tomorrow, which will break your link. Please include the essentials of the linked page in your answer. If this is meant to be a comment instead of an answer, then post it as a comment.

Comment: The link has the solution the OP is looking for. It uses DBCC INPUTBUFFER to identify the command.

Comment: Not the OP is the only person who may read this thread in the future. Your post does not meet the minimum requirements of an answer on SO. Please read [answer] in [help] for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Pred. I see the problem with only including a link.